# How to replace x and y in an equation with x[0] and x[1]?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function  of  `x` and `y`. I want to convert this into a function of `x[0]`and `x[1]` respectively ( replace ). How to proceed ?

```
import sympy as s
x,y = s.symbols('x,y')
def f(x,y):
    return (-x + 67)**2/(y**2)
```

Comment: Instead of x,y do x=list(s.symbols('x,y') .

Comment: `g = lambda x:f(x[0],x[1])`, the function `g` is what you want. It receives argument `x`, which is a list, and returns `f(x[0],x[1])`

Answer (score 1):

you can store both x and y in list

```
import sympy as s
x = list(s.symbols('x,y'))
def f(x):
    return (-x[0] + 67)**2/(x[1]**2)
```

EDIT:
I am assuming that you want to replace x and y in the body of the function by the input's first and second element respectively.

```
import sympy as s
x = list(s.symbols('x,y'))
def f(x):
    y=x[1]
    x = x[0]
    return (-x + 67)**2/(y**2)
```

Comment: Using `list()` i can create a list to store x and y. But my problem is not that. I have already a function of x and y having more than 300 terms. That has to be converted into a new function with x and y replaced by x[0] and x[1] respectively

Comment: @Shareef i think you mean replacing x and y in the function with x[0]  and y[0]. What is the expected argument of the function, is it list or two arguments x and y?

Comment: @ Mitiku Expected is list